# The meaning of gray dots located at the table fields?

Tags: datagrip

Can you tell me what is symbolized by the gray dots located next to the logotype of the field?

[image]

For example ID or PK_Players field.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gray circle means the column is not nullable. I can't find a link where this is actually documented but that's what it indicates for me.

Additionally, blue indicates an indexed column and gray indicates a non-indexed column, so in your picture, Name would not be indexed, and id is indexed, but it's a key so it gets its own key icon instead of a blue column icon. Couldn't find reference to that in their docs, either.

Comment: We added the description to the documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/database-tool-window.html#possible-icon-combinations-for-columns

Comment: These circles are also visible before any column name at the top of the currently viewed table data.